# Linked list in Python

Tags: python, linked-list

Below is my attempt at a doubly-linked list in Python (3):

```
class LinkedListNode:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left  = None
        self.right = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = self.tail = None
        self.size = 0

    def get_first(self):
        if self.head:
            return self.head.value
        raise Exception('Reading from an empty list.')

    def get_last(self):
        if self.tail:
            return self.tail.value
        raise Exception('Reading from an empty list.')

    def add_first(self, value):
        node = LinkedListNode(value)
        if self.head:
            node.right = self.head
            self.head.left = node
            self.size += 1
        else:
            self.head = self.tail = LinkedListNode(value)
            self.size = 1

    def add_last(self, value):
        node = LinkedListNode(value)
        if self.tail:
            node.left = self.tail
            self.tail.right = node
            self.size += 1
        else:
            self.head = self.tail = node
            self.size = 1

    def remove_first(self):
        if self.head:
            ret = self.head.value
            self.head = self.head.right
            self.head.left = None
            self.size -= 1
            return ret
        raise Exception('Removing from an empty list.')

    def remove_last(self):
        if self.tail:
            ret = self.tail.value
            self.tail = self.tail.left
            self.tail.right = None
            self.size -= 1
            return ret
        raise Exception('Removing from an empty list.')

    def __repr__(self):
        str = '['
        if self.size > 0:
            str += self.head.value
            node = self.head.right
            while node:
                str += ', ' + node.value
                node = node.right
        return str + ']'


def main():
    list = LinkedList()

    while True:
        cmd_line = input()
        if cmd_line == 'quit':
            break
        command_tokens = cmd_line.split()
        command = command_tokens[0]
        try:
            if command == "get_first":
                print(list.get_first())
            elif command == "get_last":
                print(list.get_last())
            elif command == "add_first":
                list.add_first(command_tokens[1])
            elif command == "add_last":
                list.add_last(command_tokens[1])
            elif command == "remove_first":
                list.remove_first()
            elif command == "remove_last":
                list.remove_last()
            elif command == "print":
                print(list)
        except Exception:
            print("Unknown command")


main()
```

How would I rewrite it in a professional manner?

Comment: Are you sure this is a version you want to review? It has gaping bugs - once the list has a node, neither `self.head` nor `self.tail` is ever updated anymore.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A better `main`

[Instead of just calling `main()` at the bottom, wrap it in `if __name__ == "__main__":`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20158605/667648) In otherwords:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This allows me to re-use your module better, see the answer I linked for more details.

## `if` chains

This portion of code:

```
        if command == "get_first":
            print(list.get_first())
        elif command == "get_last":
            print(list.get_last())
        elif command == "add_first":
            list.add_first(command_tokens[1])
        elif command == "add_last":
            list.add_last(command_tokens[1])
        elif command == "remove_first":
            list.remove_first()
        elif command == "remove_last":
            list.remove_last()
        elif command == "print":
            print(list)
```

Is a code smell to me. I would refactor this with a dictionary:

```
commands = {
    "get_first": lambda: print(list.get_first()),
    "get_last": lambda: prrint(list.get_last()),
    ...
}
```

This can then be called with:

```
commands[command]()
```

## Library Shadowing

```
list = LinkedList()
```

[`list` is already part of](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html) the standard library. I would not over shadow the name. I would change the name to something like `linked` for instance.

## `namedtuple`?

It is questionable whether you want to do this or not, but the class `LinkedListNode` is just an `__init__` method. In this case, I would usually advocate using a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead and using the `defaults` parameter added in Python 3.7 if applicable. Although, then again, `defaults` is only in 3.7... So, maybe not applicable. Still useful to know about.

## Implement `__str__` how you implemented `__repr__`

[`__str__` is for human-readable output.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) `__repr__` is for more internal information. You have implemented `__repr__` to display a human readable representation of your list. Switch to `__str__` instead.